# javascript properly split html string mantaining tags

Tags: javascript, split

I'm in need to split HTML string for further processing by my side. I have a string that contains all the HTML.

My needs keeps only in split all of them in an array, mantaining the tags. It should be splitted by `<p>`
As my further searches, it's better to not use regular expressions for that, so I need to find a proper way to do it in javascript or jquery without using external libs.

What's the best way to do it.
If it would be to use regex, it would be something like this:

```
str.match(/<p(.)>.*?<\/h\1>/g);
```

HTML example:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus porttitor quam ut ullamcorper aliquam. Morbi in dapibus tellus. Phasellus lobortis ex sapien, nec malesuada ante vulputate blandit. Nullam lacinia neque mi, at iaculis ante condimentum sed. Sed luctus purus vel dictum posuere. Ut auctor lorem a <b>congue tincidunt</b>. Nulla ut ipsum libero. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec gravida dui quis pulvinar molestie. Duis nec lacus sem. Mauris tellus nibh, tempus at mauris id, tempus eleifend libero. Nam laoreet congue suscipit. Duis sollicitudin ex eu elementum commodo.</p>

<p>Cras finibus imperdiet sapien, id sodales enim tempus sit amet. Vivamus ac ligula sagittis ante sollicitudin viverra. Pellentesque accumsan placerat massa, et aliquet purus commodo et. Aliquam molestie orci nec vehicula fermentum. In gravida ligula tempor dolor feugiat, vitae facilisis nisi facilisis. Vivamus sodales eros non vehicula scelerisque. Mauris suscipit vitae erat eu fermentum. Aenean pellentesque ut arcu consectetur malesuada. Aenean posuere ante sit amet nibh rhoncus mattis. Fusce at aliquam elit, sit amet ultrices purus. Quisque quis risus eleifend, commodo est auctor, tincidunt dui. Aliquam eros urna, tristique nec felis vel, varius eleifend nulla. Suspendisse vestibulum posuere felis in vestibulum. Nunc sit amet maximus libero. <i>Nulla placerat congue</i> lectus a ultrices.</p>
```

But since we shouldn't use it, how can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: please add some sample input and desired output in question as well,

Comment: The input is dinamyc. But it will come well formatted but could contain another tags (ol,ul,b,i). I added an example. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to use a parser. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: And you want to do this in browser JavaScript? Not Node.js?

Comment: Yes, in browser. It will be only used by admin, only 2/3 users. Everything is properly sanitized. Should be done with javascript/jquery